# HTTP Header Field not recognised

Tags: c++, boost-beast

I'm trying to make use of boost::beast in order to communicate over HTTP with a server.

I'm working on the Clientside and want to send a Request containing at least the following Header field: "X-API-SIGNATURE".

I'm creating the Request as follows:

```
http::request<http::dynamic_body> request;
request.version(11);
request.method(http::verb::get);
request.target("/test");
request.set(http::field::host, host_);
request.set("X-API-KEY", key_);
request.set("X-API-SIGNATURE", signature_);

int count_Header_Field_X_API_SIGNATUR = request.count("X-API-SIGNATURE"); // This is 1.
int count_Header_Field_X_API_Bla = request.count("X-API-BLA"); // This is 0.
```

I'm sending the Request as follows:

```
        boost::beast::http::async_write(
          *socket_,
          request,
          std::bind(
            &Testclass::on_write,
            shared_from_this(),
            std::placeholders::_1,
            std::placeholders::_2));
    }
```

After that i get the Response from the Server reporting me an Error:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Missing header: X-API-SIGNATURE","code":1,"field":"X-API-SIGNATURE"}],"credits":8}
```

I don't understand why the Server didn't recognised the "X-API-SIGNATURE" Header Field i've inserted into the Request before.

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Update: It looks like you are doing everything correctly according to the HTTP protocol, but there is something specific to your request that the server doesn't like

What is the value of `signature_`?

What is the output of the following statement?

```
std::cout << request["X-Api-Signature"] << "\n";
```

Comment: It's a String like so
"`D7ECF32D7945C48B7E730F98E542927428EC9BD2408ECF92F3D742B243867EE7`"

Comment: It looks like you are doing everything correctly according to the HTTP protocol, but there is something specific to your request that the server doesn't like.

Comment: I'm new to this and are unsure whether i'm doing everything correctly according to the HTTP Protocol. 
Thanks for your Assessment!
So i'll ask the People working at the Serverside.